# python 2.7 : create dictionary from list of sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

After performing some operations I get a `list` of `set` as following :

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth

FreqItemset(items=[u'A_String_0'], freq=303)
FreqItemset(items=[u'A_String_0', u'Another_String_1'], freq=302)
FreqItemset(items=[u'B_String_1', u'A_String_0', u'A_OtherString_1'], freq=301)
```

I'd like to create from this list :

1. RDD
2. Dictionary , for example :

   ```
   key: A_String_0 value: 303
   key: A_String_0,Another_String_1 value: 302
   key: B_String_1,A_String_0,A_OtherString_1 value: 301
   ```

I'd like to continue with calculations to produce Confidence and Lift

I tried to execute `for` loop to get each item from list .

The question is if there is another , better way to create rdd and/or lists here ?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: a) Why do you collect in the first place if you need a RDD b) What should be a class of the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure that the dictionary fits in your master node?

Comment: great tip about collect() , I forgot about it . Not sure That I understand second comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want a `RDD` simply don't collect `freqItemsets`

   ```
   model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
   freqItemsets = model.freqItemsets()
   ```

   you can of course `parallelize`

   result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
      sc.parallelize(result)
2. I am not sure why you need this (it looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
   but you can use comprehensions on the collected data:

   ```
   {tuple(x.items): x.freq for x in result}
   ```

   or

   ```
   {",".join(x.items): x.freq for x in result}
   ```

Generally speaking if you want to apply further transformations on your data don't collect and process data directly in Spark.

Also you should take a look at the Scala API. It already implements [association rules](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html#association-rules).

Comment: My porpoise is to calculate MBA . The FPGrowth is a first step . I'll calculate Confidence and Lift after , so I need access to the output of FPGrowth . That's the reason . I thought how to access the items for further calculation . Thanks a lot for help ! Currently I started with Spark and PySpark , I got the understanding have to learn scala as well :(